# How to make divs the viewing height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 columns in a `<div>`.  The `<div>` for the most columns does not extend to the max height.  I want it to be max height for the default browser view and when I decrease the browser window (mobile version).

Here is the code and css for the right column:

html:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
<div class="column-right">

    <span class="filter-image-right">
        <img src="/img/clock_library-right.png" />
        <img src="/img/heart_library-right.png" />
        <img src="/img/handshake_library-right.png" />
        <img src="/img/lamp_library-right.png" />
    </span>

    <div>
    <h6 class="right-column-heading"><img src="/img/minus.png"/> Cleaning</h6>

    </div>
        <p>
        The concept of cleaning makes little sense to young children.  For preschoolers,
        instructions like, "Put your toys away" are too vague or abstract.  You need to
        break things down for them.  "Pick up all your blocks and put them in the bin."
        "put your dolls on the bottom shelf."  The specificity of these instructions is key.
        "Clean your room!" is simply overwhelming.
        </p>

    <h6 class="right-column-heading">Make Bed</h6>

        <p>
        For a younger child; Focus on smoothing out sheets and blankets for a clear
        playing/sitting surface.
        </p>

    <h6 class="right-column-heading">test</h6>

        <p>
        The concept of cleaning makes little sense to young children.  For preschoolers,
        instructions like, "Put your toys away" are too vague or abstract.  You need to
        break things down for them.  "Pick up all your blocks and put them in the bin."
        "put your dolls on the bottom shelf."  The specificity of these instructions is key.
        "Clean your room!" is simply overwhelming.
        </p>

    <h6 class="right-column-heading">test2</h6>

        <p>
        The concept of cleaning makes little sense to young children.  For preschoolers,
        instructions like, "Put your toys away" are too vague or abstract.  You need to
        break things down for them.  "Pick up all your blocks and put them in the bin."
        "put your dolls on the bottom shelf."  The specificity of these instructions is key.
        "Clean your room!" is simply overwhelming.
        </p>

</div>
```

css:

```
.column-right { 

background-color: #d0d0d0; 
overflow-y: scroll;
padding:10px;
float: right;
margin-right:-17px;
max-height:570px;
}
```

Here is the css of the main div that holds all three columns:

```
#content-content-library {
background: white;  
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I am new to html and css, so any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

EDIT:

I have modified the css for the right column and now the left column.

```
.column-right { 
background-color: #d0d0d0; 
overflow-y: scroll;
padding:10px;
float: right;
margin-right:-17px;
height: 100vh;
}

.column-left { 
height: 100vh;
}
```

html for the left column:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="column-left">

            <div class="row">

                    <div class="left-navigation-home">
                        <img src="/img/home_library.png" />
                        <span>Home</span>

                        <span class="test">1</span>
                        <img src="/img/side_arrow.png" height="15" width="15" />
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Comment: Does it need to be IE9 backwards compatible? If not. You can use flexbox.  Here: https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/

Comment: This is one of the most annoying things imo. You have the options: **JavaScript**: quite high browser support; **[Flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**: Low browser support, easy management; and `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;`

Comment: Set the height of the .column-right class to 100vh. This will make all the columns be the height of the browser view they are in or if you want it to be the max height, set the min-height property as well to give it the 570px. I assume that is the max height you are speaking to. OR set the height on your class definition to 570px.

Comment: @Chris Ok I took off max-height off and it did work now.  Thanks

Comment: Ok one more question.  The right column now fits the div perfectly, but now the left div is not fitting the div.  I set the min-height to 570px for each column.  Not sure why it isnt working.

Comment: @Chris  I added the css for the left column and the html

Comment: So, I assume the left column is now the height of the entire screen? Change class style to `height: 570px`.

Comment: @Chris I changed the height of the left column to 570px and still it is not the full height of the screen.  The right column now is the full height of the screen which leaves the left column about 3/4 the height of the screen.  Any other things i should try?

Comment: OH! Try removing the` min-height` and reset the `height` back to `100vh`.

Comment: @Chris for the column-left css i took out min height and set the 100 vh height.  I attached the new css for each

Comment: @Chris updated the css above

Comment: And it still doesn't work?

Comment: @Chris yes still doesnt get me what I want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91638/discussion-between-chris-and-drew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `max-height` declaration that you have on the right-column class and set `height: 100vh;`.

This will give your column defined height and will make it such that they all display the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this piece of code and appy class 'equal_div' on the column that needs to be equalize.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var highestBox = 0;
        $('.equal_div').each(function(){  
                if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
                highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('.equal_div').height(highestBox);

});
</script>
```